# Python pandas: equivalent to SQL's aggregate functions?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

What is the pandas equivalent of something like:

```
select mykey, sum(Field1) as Field1, avg(Field1) as avg_field1, min(field2) as min_field2
from df
group by mykey
```

in SQL? I understand that in pandas I can do

```
grouped = df.groupby('mykey')
```

and  then

```
grouped.mean()
```

would calculate the mean for all the fields.
However, I need different aggregate functions on different columns: on some columns none at all, on others sum and avg, on other just the maximum, etc.

How do I achieve this in pandas?
Thanks!

Comment: There is section in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once) for this

Answer (score 2):

You can apply multiple functions to multiple fields:

```
    f = {'Field1':'sum',
         'Field2':['max','mean'],
         'Field3':['min','mean','count'],
         'Field4':'count'
         }

    grouped = df.groupby('mykey').agg(f)
```

Hope this helps!  Pandas is a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do it separately for each field.

Something like that could work:

`grouped = df.groupby('mykey')
grouped['Field1'].agg([np.sum, np.mean])
grouped['Field2'].min()`

Comment: No you can pass a dict consisting of columns and functions to `agg` to perform this

Comment: Nice, I haven't used that option before. I stand corrected.